# Is it better to add more indexes or add more tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

This one has been on my mind for quite a while. I have a very read-heavy database and one particular table has an index on *almost* every column. These indexes are not wasteful, and I have done my best to adjust my queries to use existing indexes so that new ones are not needed.

But still, after my best optimization of queries and indexes, I seem to have a lot of them on my table.

The only real solution that I have come up with to reduce indexes is to store some of the information (a lot of it would be duplicate or similar) in different tables with their own indexes.

I would have *several* tables with *few* indexes instead of *one* table with several *indexes*.

The problem is, two mysql practices I have learned are conflicting:

- You should never be storing duplicate information in multiple tables. Data is clean and efficient when only stored once.
- You should not have an index on every column of your table. This actually slows down queries because the mysql engine has to check each index to see if it can be used.

The two items above are not "official," I am just quoting things I have learned in the past.

So which "best practice" is the "better" practice? Which is more important?

---

EDIT: Hopefully an example will help show what I mean.

Suppose I have two users Bob (user_id 10) and jack (user_id 5). The users want to know how much they have 'earned' from the payments table.

For Bob: `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payments WHERE user_id=10`

Since this query is ran a lot for every user, an index is made on the `user_id` column which makes this query lightning fast.

Users also earn 5% for referral earnings. Jack is Bob's referral, so he get's 5% of his payments.

Bob's referral earnings: `SELECT (SUM(amount)*.05) FROM payments WHERE referral_id=10`

Note: Since multiple users can be Bob's referral, I cannot use the `user_id` column.

So, I have two options: I can either add another index on `referral_id` OR I can make another table "referral_payments" that would store another row with similar info. This table would have an index on `referral_id.`

Duplicate this times 10 and you have a situation where I either need to start making new tables or just keep making new indexes even though there is already quite a few.

Comment: could you give an example of the recent indices you added? I'm curious to see how necessary they could be. I'm probably wrong, but every time I saw such a design, there was a problem in the conception to begin with.

Comment: I am firmly in the camp of "the only good table is a fully normalized table". That being said however, it applies more in transactional DB's than in Analytical DB's, where more time and cycles are available to maintain data cleanliness. Without knowing more about your DB, and the table that yu are inquiring about,m no sensible answwer can be provided.

Comment: @Sebas - sure, let me add an example

Comment: What's the problem you are looking to solve?

Comment: All Ids used in joins shouldn't be a problem for creating indices on them. You should not doubt about creating them when necessary and there's no need *if your model is fine ceteris paribus* to create a new table for that. But I mean, theses ID don't make trouble do they? Do you have indices on other non-joined columns? Not all your columns are ids, right..?

Comment: Might be a bit late, but you might want to look at your existing design.  Having both a user id and referral id in a payments table looks odd.  I know, this comment is not related to your question, but it's something I noticed.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk - I think it looks odd myself...but how would I change this to only have one ID?

Comment: With regards to "best practices" conflicting, keep in mind that the purpose of the practice is also important. Normalization is important for keeping a model clean, but is not always the most optimized approach for analyzing the data. I am a bit rusty on my MySQL, but can you provide SQL hints as to which indexes you wish to use for specific queries?

Comment: I wish I had more time for a better response but both concepts are important.  At times in development, you will find that the solution you need to use in a particular design isn't the most ideal. I do question the referral_id being in the payments table.  I just don't typically see that data stored with payment info unless this is just a keys table.  I suggest you look into utilizing views to organize your aggregate data and then query the view.  It can be a very effective method of improving query performance on some data sets.

Comment: Is there any specific performance problem you have **measured**? Indexes can slow-down data modification, but at the same time greatly enhance searching, if used correctly (as you already noted). As long as your data model is correct and indexes are actually used, and you don't have unreasonable slow-downs on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, you should be fine.

Comment: Branko - agreed. Also, is there a reason that you could not pull some of the less used data/references out of the table into an 'Extension' table? Then index the uniqueid of the original table and use that id as a foreign key in your extension table(s). I have seen this work in practice many times.